# Is there a way to set default path for Storage Access Framework?

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

The Storage Access Framework (SAF) defaults to "Recent". Is there a way to change that default to something else (like internal storage or SD card)?

Comment: There is nothing documented for this.

Comment: Have you tried anything with Intent.setDataAndType()?

Comment: Do you mean initial path? If minimum API 26 is ok then:
    intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, pickerInitialUri);